# Jenkins job as Webhook url in GitHub app api

Tags: github, github-webhook

I have to trigger a Jenkins job from GitHub app api. I have created a GitHub app and installed on some GitHub repo. While configuring this app in the Webhook url I have given a Jenkins job url to get triggered whenever there is a pull request on the repository. But getting error as HTTP 403 No valid crumb in the request. I tried giving the crumb value in the request but still getting this error.

The Jenkins job should be triggered